# Making a Http-Request

Tags: c++, string, http, http-headers, newline

I'm trying to make a Http-Request with C++ and Boost. This is a snippet:

```
std::string request;
[..]

this->request_ = "GET / HTTP/1.1\r\n"
              "Host: api.poloniex.com\r\n"
              "Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8\r\n"
              "Accept-Language: de,en-US;q=0.7,en;q=0.3\r\n"
              "Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate\r\n"
              "Sec-WebSocket-Version: 13\r\n"
              "Sec-WebSocket-Protocol: wamp.2.json\r\n"
              "Sec-WebSocket-Extensions: permessage-deflate\r\n"
              "Sec-WebSocket-Key: czW+w3Z+3yZCKVGx6DQ1Rg==\r\n"
              "Connection: keep-alive, Upgrade\r\n"
              "Pragma: no-cache\r\n"
              "Cache-Control: no-cache\r\n"
              "Upgrade: websocket\r\n\r\n";

size_t request_length = request_.length();

boost::asio::async_write(socket_, boost::asio::buffer(request_.c_str(), request_length), boost::bind(&client::handle_write, this, boost::asio::placeholders::error, boost::asio::placeholders::bytes_transferred));
```

The problem is that the server on the other end does not recognize the end of the Http-Header and thus does not answer. I had the same problem when I tried to make the request manually with `openssl s_client -connect api.poloniex.com:443` and then sending the header. The server did not recognize the end. I had to use the `-crlf` flag, which is defined as follows:

> -crlf         - convert LF from terminal into CRLF

How can I send the CRLF's correctly with a string?

**Edit:** Replacing all "\r\n" with "\x0D\x0A" also does not work.

Comment: In my experience a minimal `HTTP` request may require a `User-Agent:` header, maybe try adding one of those?

Comment: In the console it works without a user-agent. I think if the request was not correct, the server would send an error, not just leave the connection open and don't answer.